# Online stores which stock larger cycling gear?

Tags: commuter, product-rec, clothes

I'm trying to find a source to purchase large-sized bicycle gear.  I'm having a hard time finding all sorts of gear.  I've been looking for padded mountain bike shorts, but can't find anything that would fit a 52"-ish waist.  3XL gloves, 4XLT shorts and shirts, are all things I'm looking to find.  I'm riding ~30 miles per day, so I'm looking to add comfort as my daily mileage continues to rise (shooting for 40 miles per day).  Rain and/or winter gear is a plus.

What stores stock larger-than-normal cycling gear?

Comment: Converted to CW, there will (hopefully) be multiple answers. I know of no bibs shorts as comfortable as Aerotech's, though. (Gary's answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Aero Tech Designs](http://www.aerotechdesigns.com/). They have shorts, jerseys, outerwear and liners and go up to 6XL in many items and styles.  The have large gloves as well (under accessories).

As a guy who fluctuates between XL and XXL one recommendation I want to make is that you consider [bib shorts](http://www.aerotechdesigns.com/bibshort.htm).  You can wear them under any kind of shorts if you don't want the lycra look. The primary advantage of bib shorts is that everything stays in place, rather than shifting, or in my case the waist band rolling down.

Comment: I have a pair of their bibs and they're insanely comfortable.

Comment: Are you guys wearing the regular ~$65 bibs or the $139 elites?